# operator++ as both a postfix and prefix doesn't work with clang

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operators, language-lawyer

I tried to write an operator that can be used both as a prefix and a postfix operator

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct B { 
  // ...
};

template<typename ...T>
void operator++(B, T...) {
  std::cout << ((sizeof...(T) == 0) ? "prefix" : "postfix") << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  B b;
  b++;
  ++b;
}
```

GCC compiles and works fine with this, but clang says

> main.cpp:9:24: error: parameter of overloaded post-increment operator must have type 'int' (not 'T...')
>
> ```
> void operator++(B, T...) {
> ```

Who is right?

---

Thanks to anyone who helped me understand GCC's behavior. I filed a new Clang bug report:

http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=14995

Comment: I'm not sure this was intended to work - the wording says "non-member function with two parameters (the second of which shall be of type int) ..."

Comment: This is clang's reason-for-being.  If you write stoopid code then clang reserves the right to tell you about it with a clear error message.  Good error messages trumping a shoddy language standard, a point of view that hasn't been applied enough.  Admirably wrong, perhaps, I do like what they are trying to do.  Don't put the poodle in the microwave programming.

Comment: But the point is that it is possible to generate a valid specialisation for the function (without requiring that the parameter pack always be empty (which is illegal)).

Comment: @Hans Calling the C++ language standard “shoddy” is lacking perspective. There are few (less than five? Off the top of my head I can name one) language standards that have a more rigorous language and definition.

Comment: What if you add an explicit instantiation: `template void operator++<int>(B, int);`?

Comment: @KerrekSB doesn't work, already tried, same error

Comment: @KonradRudolph out of curiosity, what is that one that you can think of?

Comment: @AK4749 Ada. There are probably more (Lisp, Scheme, C, Haskell) but I’m not actually sure about any of those.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'd add Algol 68 to the list (though it's nearly irrelevant). The C standard is about on a par with C++. I'd say Common Lisp is a couple of steps behind. I can't really say about the others.

Comment: @jpalecek but it is not a nonmember function, but a nonmember function template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:** (*not deleted as it may contain useful information*)

I would say it all boils down to whether an overloaded operator **template** is considered to be an overloaded operator or not. Logically, I would like to think this is not the case, and Clang is wrong: I believe the template *should* be first selected as a candidate for overload resolution based on name and signature compatibility, then instantiated, then (possibly) selected. The way I see it, only after instantiation the compiler should check whether the resulting **function** has the proper amount of arguments or not.

But that is only my *opinion*. Per § 13.5.7/1 about overloading of the postfix `operator ++`:

*"If the function is a member function with one parameter (which shall be of type int) or a non-member **function** with two parameters (the second of which shall be of type int), it defines the postfix increment operator ++ for objects of that type"*

The Standard does not seem to clarify whether a function **template** shall be considered as a **function** for what concerns the restrictions on the signature of legal operator overloads (at least, I could not find any sentence that solves this ambiguity). As long as this is true, this question can hardly be given a clear answer, and we are left with *opinions*.

But I would like to mention another relevant aspect of the matter: **consistency**.

Although it is true that the code in the question's text does not compile on Clang, the following does:

```
template<typename... Ts>
int operator + (X x1, Ts... args)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I do not see any conceptual difference between the two cases: if the signature of the operator overload is to be checked *before instantiation*, then the above definition should not compile either. If this is not the case, then the code in the question's text should compile.

So the answer in my opinion is that either GCC is right, or they are both wrong.

**UPDATE:**

As @JesseGood and @SethCarnegie correctly point out, per 14.7/4:

*"A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized."*

Moreover, per 14.6/8:

*"No diagnostic shall be issued for a template for which a valid specialization can be generated."*

Thus, it seems Clang is indeed wrong and **no compilation error shall be produced** for the operator function template in the question's text.

Comment: the function template you show is "illformed no diagnostic required" because all instantiations of the template require an empty parameter pack. this is specified somewhere in clause 14.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: i see. i'll give it a second thought and delete my answer if I can't patch it

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I am having troubles finding your statement in the Standard. are you referring to § 14.5.6.1/6 by any chance?

Comment: try to search for the example containing "+;". unfortunately i dont have the spec at hand currently. but i am sure, because i made a corresponsing PR to clang back then about having an uion base class "T..." which among other examples led to this wording.

Comment: in the end i kept my (edited) answer even though the conclusion is now different from the original one, because the spirit is the same: i believe the standard does not clearly define what the behavior should be (although i do have an interpretation of my own), and consistency should be valued in presence of ambiguity. clang does not seem to behave consistently.

Comment: `The Standard does not seem to clarify whether a function template shall be considered as a function` I think it does. How about 13.5p1: `A specialization of an operator function template is also an operator
function.`

Comment: @JesseGood: that seems very relevant, but do we have a specialization here? i would say we only have an operator function template

Comment: I thought we did, an instantiation is a specialization as from 14.7p4: `A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either instantiated or explicitly specialized`. I also thought [Seth Carnegie's comment was spot on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369468/operator-as-both-a-postfix-and-prefix-doesnt-work-with-clang/14378234#comment19982793_14369468).

Comment: @JesseGood: well, we do have an instantiation, but the point here is whether the signature should be checked *before* or *after* instantiation. after instantiation we all agree the signature should be compliant. but before? Clang is checking the signature even before the template gets instantiated (even if your client code contains no invocation of `operator ++`)

Comment: Well that is mentioned in 14.6p8: `No diagnostic
shall be issued for a template for which a valid specialization can be generated.`

Comment: @JesseGood: so that makes Clang's behavior definitely wrong, is it so?

Comment: I thought so, yes (unless I am missing something). The OP might have another opinion though as he is much more well-versed on the standard then me.

Comment: @JesseGood: well, that would kind of change my answer completely then. i am wondering whether i should not delete it

Comment: The answer does have useful information, but the choice is up to you. Users with 10k or more rep will still be able to read it.

Comment: @JesseGood: ok, I just edited and gave credit. if that will turn out to be wrong again, i will delete it to avoid confusion.